# Is there a way to restore files that have been deleted with an OS?

Tags: windows, boot, kali-linux, restore, recovery

I dual booted kali with Windows 10, but when I reboot my computer or try to disable secure startup (to exit kali OS), it says that there's no bootable devices found, even though I am absolutely positive I made kali boot on a disk partition. So the kali OS works, but all my files are gone (I used UEFI and I do not have the windows option)

Here's how I booted:

Got a kali iso, converted it into a bootable usb drive, booted up my laptop, disabled secure startup, did an advanced startup and booted kali. I did some date time and language settings after booting up the Kali OS, and when it said Disk Partitioning (choose disk partition) I used the recommended one: Boot from a single disk. After that, the OS installed, loaded, and I tried shutting my computer down... and boom. no windows option.

I think I may have messed up with the disk partitioning, and i am unsure how to restore my operating system/files. I ran `locate system32` as root and found nothing, so I have reason to believe that all my files are gone. If anyone has any suggestions on how to restore lost files from an OS, that would be amazing and really helpful.

If not, is there a way to boot Windows from Kali using a USB? Also, how would I go about finding the product key if my laptop came preinstalled with Windows and was bought a considerable amount of time ago? Any information would be really useful.

Answer (score 0):

The partition of your OS containing your personal files is likely still intact. However, the EFI/Boot partition may have been tampered with by the Kali OS you installed. My first suggestion would be to try and use BootBCD to restore the MBR/BCD of the Windows OS. I usually use Hirens to accomplish this when I manage to break my Windows install.

Comment: Alright, I will try it. Thank you!